# Azure forcing https for no reason?

Tags: azure, ssl, https, web-config, azure-web-app-service

**TL;DR Changing my web.config file does nothing and HTTPS is forced on all domains despite that the entire rule is removed from web.config**

**Long version:**

I previously read this tutorial on how to configure https on your azure web-app and force it to deliver only https content:

https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/

Now, I want to change so that some subdomains do not force https, I read about it and was told that you could add this line to your web.config to remove the rule form certain domains:

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^subdomain\.mydomain\.com$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

That all seemed nice, but I couldn't get it to work. Now, **here's when it gets weird:**

As a troubleshoot step, I removed the entire "Force HTTPS"-rule from my web.config, and azure STILL forces HTTPS on all domains. It still works for the normal domain, but for all subdomains that do not have certificate files I'm given an error response when I try to connect. It's as if the web.config file is cached, meaning that all domains are looking for certificate files and those that cannot find any that match them just report back that something is wrong.

When I try to visit subdomains, this is the response I get:

[image: This is the response from subdomains]

Comment: The exact same thing has happened to me recently. I have an old Azure site that is working fine and does not use SSL.  But last week I tried deploying a new site (that is also a subdomain) and I get the same certificate error.  I almost think that they're forcing us to use SSL certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your web.config file, in the last line you set `redirectType="Permanent"`.  I suspect what you're seeing is an artifact of your browser caching the redirect settings.

Comment: This is very likely! I'm excited about this, had to reply as soon as I saw it. I'm going to try it asap!

Comment: This was indeed the case! When I opened my site from another computer the redirect was no longer there!

So, I hastily added the rule again, just as written in my first question. But now it redirects for **all** subdomains, again =/

Can anyone see if there is something incorrect  with the rule itself?

Comment: Actually, I guess that is another question. This was the correct answer, thanks a lot :D